# Calling web service method from fiddler

Tags: web-services, fiddler

I have one web service which accepting one parameter.

Webservice Method:

[ActionName("GetCustomers")]

```
[HttpPost]

[AcceptVerbs("GET","HEAD")]

public bool getcustomers(string id)
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(id.ToString());

    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Result.txt"))
    {
        file.WriteLine(result);
    }

    return false;
}
```

if i run below url in fiddler ..GetCustomer method is invoking....

```
url : http://localhost:49809/Import/GetCustomers/test
```

if i pass with json format like in screen shot ;

[image: screen shot]

my webmethod is not calling....Let me know why if pass json format it is not calling.. is is giving error :HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `ContentType` to `Content-Type` and remove the quotation marks around its value.

The line should read: `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8`